# Android stop infinite repeat in CoverFlow (moondroid)

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, coverflow

Is there any way to prevent Moondroid Coverflow (https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) from automatically connecting the last object to the first object once it gets to the end.

```
setShouldRepeat(false);
```

seems to do nothing other than break the coverflow when there are less than four objects. It completely prevents scrolling.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: I could not, but my solution was to initialize it with 5 transparent objects. I also tried using the onScrollListner to prevent it from scrolling past the end and beginning. It didn't really work but with a bit more effort maybe there is a workaround